# Why getClass() used in the piece of code?

Tags: java-me

I am trying to access the audio file from the jar,for doing that i wrote a code,like

```
...
try {
   InputStream is = 
     getClass().getResourceAsStream("audio.wav");
   Player player = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/X-wav");
   p.start();
} 
catch(IOException ioe) {
} 
catch(MediaException me) {
}
...
```

but here in this snippet,what is the use of getClass()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to get the class of the current object, so in turn you can access resources.  `getResourceAsStream` loads resources from the class loader associated with the class.  See the documentation for [`Object.getClass`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) and [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).